# Como pegar a url gerado ao acessar o link de foto do instagram usando /media/?size=l no final

Tags: php, api

Estou tentando pegar a url que é exibida(trocada) ao acessar um link como por exemplo no instagram https://www.instagram.com/p/B9MjyquAfkE/media/?size=l, o link gerado após o clique, vem da api do instagram, e como esse mesmo link gerado tem tempo de expiração, não tem como usar ele por muito tempo. Existe alguma maneira via php, para pega-lo sem mostrar a página em si do link?
Tentei usar o curl, mas não consegui o resultado.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '"'.$dadosItemInstagram['imagem'].'"');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

O array $dadosItemInstagram['imagem'], é o que contém o link. Andei lendo bastante antes de vir aqui, e pelo que entendi o instagram apartir de uma autorização da conta da acesso a api deles, pra por exemplo exibir imagens ou vídeos nos sites, só que o link tem uma certa duração então estou preso nessa parte, a solução que encontrei foi adicionar o `/media/?size=l` , no final do link, então sei se é a melhor também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que acontece é que esse link é redirecionado pra outra url, então você precisa que o CURL aceite redirecionamento. Você consegue fazer isso setando a opção `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: Funcionou muito bem, mas só consegui reproduzir colocando um link em `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "(um_link_aqui)");`  , se eu colocar uma variável que contem o link ele não da certo, não sei se é possível também, tem essa possibilidade?

Comment: É  possível também retornar somente a url redirecionada?

Comment: Sim, isso já está sendo feito com a função `curl_getinfo`: `$urlRedirecionada = $info['url'];`